# mysql query 2 table with looping value

Tags: mysql

Table 1:

```
code | value1 | date1 
515  | MD001  | 2016-07-01 
515  | MD002  | 2016-07-03
612  | UD005  | 2016-08-01
612  | UD006  | 2016-08-03
612  | UD007  | 2016-08-06
```

Table 2:

```
code | value2 | date2
515  | FC003  | 2016-07-02
515  | FC004  | 2016-07-04
612  | QQ008  | 2016-08-02
612  | QQ009  | 2016-08-04
```

Desired query output is:

```
Code | Value1 | date1      | value2 | date2
515  | MD001  | 2016-07-01 | FC003  | 2016-07-02
515  | MD002  | 2016-07-03 | FC004  | 2016-07-04
612  | UD005  | 2016-08-01 | QQ008  | 2016-08-02
612  | UD006  | 2016-08-03 | QQ009  | 2016-08-04
612  | UD007  | 2016-08-06 |        |
```

I have try to query but the result always looping in 'value2'. Can you help me guys?

Comment: Use mysqli_query two times. Wheres the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
 firstTable.code,
 firstTable.value1,
 firstTable.date1,
 secondTable.value2,
 secondTable.date2
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
    T1.*,
    @rn1 := @rn1 + 1 AS row_number
    FROM Table1 AS T1
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn1 := 0) AS var
) AS firstTable

LEFT JOIN
(

    SELECT 
    T2.*,
    @rn2 := @rn2 + 1 AS row_number
    FROM Table2 AS T2
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn2 := 0) AS var
) AS secondTable
ON firstTable.code = secondTable.code AND firstTable.row_number = secondTable.row_number;
```

**Note:** A simple inner join in this case won't suffice.

That's why enumerating the rows in each table and assigning a row number to each record would be the first task.

Later making an `inner join` between these two enumerated tables on `code` and `row number` would generate the expected result set.

Comment: The result just 1 row only

Answer (score 0):

select distinct code,Value1, date1 ,value2 ,date2 
from Table1 as t1
Join Table2 as t2 on t1.code=t2.code;

Comment: unfortunately this query will return 4 rows for this set of input.

Comment: This query will return same row in "value2"